Why does my rigid body stop rolling after 10 seconds?
I have a rigid body that I'm trying to use for a satisfying marble run, however it seems that midway through the ball just stops rolling after 10 seconds. I verify End frame of Playback/Render frame range, I verify the end in time line and the cache settings in scene properties but nothing changes, please help me


I’ve vaguely remember there’s some limit in the scene properties as to how long a rigid body simulation can last. But, why did you crop your screenshot so tight?

Go into scene properties, simulation settings, and change simulation range.

sir i trie it but still not working

@SalahEddineMerchi can you share your blend file?

how i ca, shar it with you?

i found mini solution, before you start your project you must specify your frame first and then start your work, i try this method in new project and its work but in my old project doesn't work , wich mean  i will start over!!!

@Lynx095 When the Cache of the Rigid Body World is set to end at frame 950, it does not change anything to set the Simulation Range separately. This is only used to set a different range than the scene range for Simulation Nodes which do not override that range themselves. This has nothing to do with the rigid body simulation.
